# what type of adjective is "what"?

Tags: adjectives

Consider the sentence, *What folly!"*

1. identify the adjective in the above sentence
2. What type of adjective is this?

According to me, ***what*** is the adjective. It looks like an interrogative adjective but we are not asking a question here.

Comment: In your example, it's called "exclamative what".

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to call ***what*** an "adjective", but I'd say ***exclamative*** sounds more like a noun to me, compared to the obviously adjectival ***exclamatory***. And according to [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exclamative+what%2Cexclamatory+what&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) the latter has a far longer history of being used before ***what.***

Comment: It's an **adjective**. "Exclamatory" is a cover term for expressions conveying an exclamatatory meaning, not just for exclamative clauses and phrases such as "What a car that was! and "What folly!" Exclamative "what" is most certainly an adjective. It always occurs in NPs with a following head. In "What folly!", "what" is an internal modifier. In "What a car that was!" it's an external modifier, i.e. outside the nominal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What folly!*

This is a verbless exclamative expression consisting of just an exclamative noun phrase, where "what" has the syntax of an **adjective**.

It is typically referred to as 'exclamative what', and it always occurs in NPs with a following head.

In "What folly!", "what" is an internal modifier, while in "What a car that was!" it's an external modifier, i.e. outside the nominal.

Comment: How what is this folly?  It's very what. Some follies are quite what, but this folly is whater.  It might be the whatest folly I've seen! I can't imagine a more what folly than this.

Comment: @JamesK What's your point? So it doesn't have inflectional forms, and it never occurs in post-head or predicative position. Exclamative "what" only occurs as modifier in NP structure, i.e. with a following head. As a modifier it may occur in either internal or external position. What else can it be other than an adjective?

Comment: Just pulling your leg. But I don't think it's very useful to force words to fit into these parts of speech. The reason one might want to know which part of speech a word is would be so you could predict its inflections and syntax.

Comment: @JamesK Yes to syntax. I'd say it's so that we can determine its function in the clause, in this case as modifier. Students who are expected to draw tree diagrams need to know.